# how can create border image for bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I create border image on the left and right side of bootstrap `.container` class and then repeat the image vertically?

The container has a `background-color` and several instances of container are still on the page.

In fact I want to have an border image on both the left and right side of the main container place.

```
.container {
    border-image: url("../tasavir/ghaleb/paein-header.jpg");
    border-repeat: repeat-y;
    border-position: right;
}
```

This code did not work.

My theme image are there : [the website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY3cy.jpg)

Comment: try add `border-width:10px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks MrGood. but the best way to do that is it :

```
.container {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 13px;
    border-image: url('../path/to/pic.jpg') 0 13 stretch repeat;
    border-image-outset: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what you are looking for:

[**Bootply Example Here**](http://www.bootply.com/7FfbzPhwQe)

**CSS**

```
.container {

background-color:blue;
height:400px;
border-image: url('...images/your_image');
border-image-width: 0 60px 0 60px;
border-image-slice: 0 400px 0 400px;
border-image-repeat:repeat;

}
```

You will need to change the border-image-width and border-image-repeat to accommodate the particular image you wish to use.